# Find the volume of water that will remain in the container below after tilting it $45$ degrees

Tags: calculus, volume

A container in the shape of a right circular cylinder is initially filled with water and resting on a flat, horizontal surface. However, the container was slowly tilted until the plane of its base
$45^o$  with the horizontal plane. If the radius and height of the container measure $6$m and $8$m
respectively, then the percentage of the volume of water that will remain in the container, in relation to the initial volume, is equal to? (Answer:$25 $%)

I try

I made the figure but I am not able to calculate the volume $BFC$

$V_t=\pi r^2h = \pi . 6^2.8 =288 \pi m^3$

[image]

Comment: Your graph is perfect. You should be able to solve it yourself by dividing the tilted cylinder into $3$ parts as seen in your picture.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc  I couldn't visualize how to calculate the volume of these parts. Can you help?

Comment: @smcc No, it is just the 45 degree angle that is misleading (and the presence of the useless line FH). EB is the base, diameter 12, of which FB was deduced to be 8. I too though at first BC was th cylinder base, which would make it a really easy question.

Comment: I know, I deleted my comment.

Comment: The answer also cannot be 25%. If you draw a line (really a plane) from the midpoint of EG to the midpoint of BC, then you split the cylinder in half. In the bottom half, the section filled with water is exactly the same shape and volume as the empty part, so the water in the bottom half is already 25% of the whole cylinder. There is water in the top half too, so the water is more than 25%. Given the misleading drawing (the 45 degree angle being drawn between the ground and the side instead of the base and the line FH) it is likely that there is some mistake in the question.

Comment: @smcc Would it? I don't see how that would be 25%. On a 2d drawing the parts are represented by equal triangles, but as parts of the 3d cylinder they are very different.

Comment: This webpage gives a formula for the volume of water in this case (it also links to a page with a for other cases): http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.16/h/brian2.html

Comment: Using that formula, the answer (25%) is correct when the height is about 1.128 times the radius.

Comment: This is a high school problem so you can't use integral

Comment: There are other alternatives: $20$%, $50$% and $75$% but the examining board considered $25$%. It could be an error by the examining board

Comment: If you cannot use calculus to solve the problem, why did you add the "calculus" tag?